# Perimeter and Area of a Big and Small Square

Tags: word-problem

The Perimeter of a big square is seven times the perimeter of a small square. What fraction of the area of the big square is the area of the small square?

I have tried to set it as s and so the perimeter of the small square would be 4s and the perimeter of the big square would be 28s. Then after that dividing the perimeter by 4 so I could find the length of each side (as a variable). The length of the big squares side is 7s (28s/4), and the length of the small square was defined before as s. After that the area would be side*side so the area of the big square is 49s^2 and the area of the small square is s^2. Thus, the fraction of the small square out of the big square is s^2/49s^2 which simplifies out to 1/49.

Comment: What have you tried?  As with any word problem, in the absence of other inspiration assign variables to the likely things.  Let the side of the small square be $s$.  What is the perimeter?  the area?  the perimeter of the large square?  the area of the large square?

Comment: Your edited post has a correct solution, good job!  Perhaps you might like to post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it as s and so the perimeter of the small square would be 4s and the perimeter of the big square would be 28s. Then after that dividing the perimeter by 4 so I could find the length of each side (as a variable). The length of the big squares side is 7s (28s/4), and the length of the small square was defined before as s. After that the area would be side*side so the area of the big square is 49s^2 and the area of the small square is s^2. Thus, the fraction of the small square out of the big square is s^2/49s^2 which simplifies out to 1/49.